# UDP socket with "winsock"

Tags: sockets, winapi, udp, c++-cli

I send a UDP request to a server, although it returns me the right answer on wireshark but in my code with " recvfrom " I get what I sent.

Code :

```
char* udp_recv;
udp_recv = (char*)malloc(256);
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
for (i; i < 1; i++)
{

    String^ delimStr = ":";
    array<Char>^ delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray();

    array<String^>^ addrPort = addr[i]->Split(delimiter);

    char *cAddr, *cPort, *cPartAddr;

    cAddr = (char*)malloc(16);
    cPort = (char*)malloc(16);
    cPartAddr = (char*)malloc(16);

    ConvertStringToChar(addrPort[0], cAddr, 16);
    ConvertStringToChar(addrPort[1], cPort, 16);

    SOCKADDR_IN udpbind;

    udpbind.sin_family = AF_INET;
    udpbind.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    udpbind.sin_port = htons((u_short)atoi(cPort));

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&udpbind, sizeof(udpbind)) < 0) std::cout << "Erreur" << std::endl;

    delimStr = ".";
    delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray();

    array<String^>^ partAddr = addrPort[0]->Split(delimiter);

    std::string send("SAMP");

    int j = 0;
    for (j; j < 4; j++)
    {
        ConvertStringToChar(partAddr[j], cPartAddr, 16);
        send += (char)atoi(cPartAddr);
    }
    send += (char)(atoi(cPort) & 0xFF);
    send += (char)(atoi(cPort) >> 8 & 0xFF);
    send += "i";

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(cAddr);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons((u_short)atoi(cPort));

    sendto(s, (char*)send.c_str(), strlen((char*)send.c_str()), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

    struct sockaddr_in recv;
    int client_len = sizeof(recv);
    recv_size = recvfrom(s, udp_recv, 256, 0, NULL, NULL);

    udp_recv[recv_size] = '\0';

    std::cout << udp_recv << std::endl;

    free(cPartAddr);
    free(cAddr);
    free(cPort);

}
closesocket(s);
```

Thanks !

Comment: The code linked to isn't C++. What is it?

Comment: It's C++ CLR with windows form.

Comment: That's a snippet of c++/cli, but I suspect you knew that @IInspectable , mixed with good ol' C to get `malloc` and `free`. Not such a good idea mixing that stuff unless you know exactly what you're doing, Riehl. Also a good idea to put the code int the post, not in a link to another site because your question and any answers will be useless once pastebin juggles its URLs. And to kick you while you are down, [the minimal and complete code is recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not snippets.

Comment: Recommendation: use the .Net socket libraries if you're going to use .Net. Better integration and easier to use.

Comment: @user4581301: How could I know, that this is C++/CLI, and not, say, C++/CX? I don't see anything C++/CLI-specific about the code.

Comment: Alright. You got me there.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Should you be using UDP to send a request and expect something back?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer, but this looks suspicious:

```
udp_recv = (char*)malloc(256);

...

recv_size = recvfrom(s, udp_recv, 256, 0, NULL, NULL);

udp_recv[recv_size] = '\0';
```

Two immediate problems:

1. If the number of bytes received is actually 256, then you'll be assigning `udp_recv[256]=0`.
2. If the result is an error recvfrom returns -1 (SOCKET_ERROR).  You'll be assigning `udp_recv[-1]=0`;

In both cases, the valid index ranges of udp_recv is [0..255].  -1 and 256 are invalid index ranges. Thus, undefined behavior.

Check for socket error and allocate the buffer to be 1 more byte larger than what you declare the buffer size to be.

Comment: Also not the answer, but all of those `malloc`ed arrays can be statically allocated. `char* udp_recv; udp_recv = (char*)malloc(256);` can be `char udp_recv[256]`. This gets rid of a bunch of manual memory management and usually makes debugging a bit easier because you can snoop in the entire array with a debugger.

Comment: @user4581301 - agreed.  He could just declare `char udp_recv[257]` and be done.

Comment: And do not cast the return value of malloc .

Comment: @icbytes - I'm not sure how can avoid casting the value of `malloc` given that it returns a `void*`.  Perhaps C allows for this, but C++ definitely will generate a compiler error when attempting to assign a `void*` expression to a `char*` variable without an explicit cast.